How can I create a copy/clone of a sheet in a spreadsheet document using ODFDOM?
I need to create a full copy of a table sheet in an ODF Spreadsheet document using ODF Toolkit.
I'm trying to clone like this:
ods.getContentRoot().appendChild(ods.getContentRoot().getChildNodes().item(1).cloneNode(true));

The copy is created, but incorrectly. When opening the saved file with OpenOffice Calc - the cell formatting is not copied, when opening in Microsoft Excel - the cells are not filled in the copy.
I use ODF Toolkit version 0.12.0.
